# PHP Grabbing Option ID from HTML Select

Tags: php, html, html-select

Currently setting up a form for users to select aircraft information from. Currently, the form allows users to select an airplane and in return when the form is submitted it passes the value"aircraft type" to an API. Due to this, I cannot set the values to be the registration of the airplanes so have put this into the ID for now (open to suggestions).

```
<select name="type" id="plane-list">
        <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>
        <?php
        foreach($allaircraft as $item){
        ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $item->registration; ?>" value="<?php echo $item->icao; ?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?> - <?php echo $item->registration; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

As you can from above these are all dynamic values which change over time so hard coding the options are not possible.

So summed up I need to pull the ID or `$item->registration;` instead of ICAO code. This then needs to be set as a variable so that I can call a function with this code.

Let me know if you need me to clear up anything. Don't normally questions on here so be nice.

Comment: PHP won't "grab" anything from there, unless you'd post it to the server-side.